# Force every new terminal to open in new tab

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have the habit of opening a terminal using the "Open terminal here" command in folders. This causes a few terminals to remain open while I don't really use them anymore, or I get confused which terminal was serving which purpose.

I know I can label terminal tabs and such, but can I force a new terminal that is being openened, to become a new tab in a terminal screen (if there is one open already?) This way I always have them tabbed in a single terminal.

**EDIT**
Okay, so it's been a while and my linux mojo has improved a lot. So the current solution to this situation for me has been using `tmux`. It's a little more advanced than regular terminals and tabs but once I got the hang of it (about an hour of trying) I'm very pleased with the way of going about things.

First of all, I made sure that whenever I opened a terminal using `ctrl-alt-t`, it would open tmux by default. This can be achieved by adding the following line in your `.bashrc` file after all the aliases:

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec 'tmux
```

Now everytime you spawn a terminal using `ctrl-alt-t` you will be presented with a `tmux`.

To make sure you only have one terminal open at the same time I did the following:

First of all, you can reattach a session in `tmux` by running `tmux attach -d`. This will disconnect all other clients connected to this session. This works fine **if you are the only person using the sessions.**

But, if you don't have a session running it will say it did not find any sessions. Ergo, you need something like if(nosession) { tmux } else { tmux attach -d }. To do this create of append to your `~/.tmux.conf` file the following line:

```
#if run as "tmux attach", create a session if one does not already exist
new-session -n $HOST
```

(Thanks to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103898/how-to-start-tmux-with-attach-if-a-session-exists))

In my `.bashrc` file, I changed the line added previously to the following:

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec 'tmux attach -d'
```

What this does is detach all other clients from the `tmux` session. When you do this, all other terminals close. They close because this line also makes sure that when you open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t), it immediatly starts a tmux session.

Ergo, `attach -d` kills the other sessions. So this is the closest fix I could get and I'm rather happy with it! :)

The only thing I would still like is that when I press `ctrl-alt-t` it opens up my current session and also creates a new window. I haven't figured that out yet so feel free to help!

Comment: Press ctr+shift+t to open tab in terminal.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. However, as I said, I frequently open tabs from within a directory using the plugin "Open terminal here" (this is default in Xubuntu for example). These open a new window. I would like these to be opened as a new tab in the already existing terminal window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately opening new tabs in the existing gnome-terminal session has been a wanted feature for a several years now - see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/117333).

It would be possible to hack something together, though. For instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191093/1064565) answer provides a hack to open a new tab in the current window of gnome-terminal.

Comment: Excellent. +1 for the link to the bug report. I can only encourage everybody to click the "this affects me too" link on top to draw some attention to this. Also +1 for the hack. Great answer!