# Can new terminals be spawned as tabs instead of windows?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome-terminal, mate

I am on Ubuntu Mate, 16.04, I ssh into a raspberry pi by clicking a panel app.
The app spawns a new mate terminal session. The only downside, is I get multiple open windows. If it is possible, I would like to know how a new session of mate terminal emulator could be spawned as a new tab, rather than a new window.

Comment: ctrl-shift-t doesn't work?

Comment: Have you looked into using a multiplexer, such as GNU `screen` or `tmux`?  You'd get these, plus additional benefits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force every new terminal to open in new tab](http://askubuntu.com/questions/440777/force-every-new-terminal-to-open-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in 16.04 the choice was removed from the menu and by default  new terminals are opened in Windows. This was bothering me as well. This can be changed by opening `gnome-terminal`, choosing <kbd>Terminal</kbd> then <kbd>Preferences</kbd> from the applications menu bar and changing the dropdown selection from Windows to Tab.

Note: This was tested on 16.04 on `gnome-terminal` version 3.18.3

In Mate Terminal this option doesn't exist. You can either install gnome-terminal easily with the command `sudo apt update&&sudo install gnome-terminal` or open a new tab in mate-terminal with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Tested under 16.04 with `mate-terminal` v.1.12.1

Comment: what tab might that be under?

Comment: @j0h Updated answer... ;-)

Comment: I see the section, and I tried this, but in mate-terminal there is evidently no effect. I also tried rebooting.

Comment: @j0h That's odd, I don't find this section in mate-terminal... Updated answer... ;-)